# Echelon Form Clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, education, matrix-equations

I know that a $3\times 3$ has 7  echelon forms, I found them all out but I was wondering why this is not an echelon form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0  &1 \\ 
 0& 0 &0 \\ 
 0&0  & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in row echelon form.

Row echelon form of rank $1$ are of the form of

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0  &1 \\ 
 0& 0 &0 \\ 
 0&0  & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1  & * \\ 
 0& 0 &0 \\ 
 0&0  & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1 &*  &* \\ 
 0& 0 &0 \\ 
 0&0  & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It satisfy the following criteria

- all nonzero rows (rows with at least one nonzero element) are above any rows of all zeroes (all zero rows, if any, belong at the bottom of the matrix), and
- the leading coefficient (the first nonzero number from the left, also called the pivot) of a nonzero row is always strictly to the right of the leading coefficient of the row above it (some texts add the condition that the leading coefficient must be $1$.

There are $8$ of them rather than $7$ of them.

Comment: My textbook says there are seven, but I guess it is a problem of definition by the author. Thank you.

Comment: interesting, I wonder if the excluded the zero matrix.